# Separate logic into different modules with the common global object

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, telethon

I'm working on a telegram bot using [telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/).

I have multiple handlers for multiple commands. For example:

`bot.py`:

```
bot = TelegramClient('bot', TELEGRAM_API_ID, TELEGRAM_API_HASH).start(bot_token=TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN)

@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/start'))
def start_handler(event):
    ...


@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/time'))
def time_handler(event):
    ...


@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/timezone'))
def timezone_handler(event):
    ...


def run():
    bot.run_until_disconnected()
```

And I start it (calling `run()`) from the different module:

`start.py`

```
from bot import run
run()
```

As the number of commands grows the `bot.py` module becomes more and more cumbersome. What would be a better way to separate handlers into different modules having the `bot` object the same for all?

My initial ideas are:

1. Having initializing methods for different handlers groups:

`time.py`

```
def init_time_handlers(bot):
    @bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/time'))
    def time_handler(event):
        ...
    
    
    @bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/timezone'))
    def timezone_handler(event):
        ...
```

`run.py`:

```
from bot import bot
from time import init_time_handlers
# import other handlers modules

init_time_handlers(bot)
# init other handlers

bot.run_until_disconnected()
```

2. Having a single mapping file and handlers in separate modules:

`time.py`

```
def time_handler(event):
    ...


def timezone_handler(event):
    ...
```

`bot.py`

```
from time import time_handler, timezone_handler
# import other handlers modules

bot = TelegramClient('bot', TELEGRAM_API_ID, TELEGRAM_API_HASH).start(bot_token=TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN)

@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/start'))
def start_handler(event):
    ...


bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/time'))(time_handler)
bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/timezone'))(timezone_handler)
# map other handlers
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can separate the functions into different files based on their usefulness, for example:

You have three files, one called `random_utilities.py`, one called `time_utilities.py` and the last one called `main.py`.

Now, in the `main.py` file, you can write your main code, something like this:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
import time_utilities, random_utilities
api_id = 123536
api_hash = "97acafjf34ldsa34esda12"


bot = TelegramClient("botsession", api_id, api_hash)
bot.start(bot_token = "1072451454:CCAB15fACd74sH0qDdsajeoqU")

time_utilities.main(bot)
random_utilities.main(bot)

def main():
    bot.run_until_disconnected()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You need to import the other files in the main one, and write in that file the functions you need, in this way:

random_utilities.py:

```
from telethon.sync import events

def main(bot):
    @bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/random'))
    async def start_handler(event):
        print(f"RANDOM: {event.message.message}")


    @bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/randomword'))
    async def time_handler(event):
        print(f"RANDOMWORD: {event.message.message}")


    @bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/randomint'))
    async def timezone_handler(event):
        print(f"RANDOMINT: {event.message.message}")
```

And you can structure all other files in this way.

It's convenient if you have to manage many commands, you divide them into various files so if you have to fix bugs, you can immediately understand where it is without scrolling through all the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that is one of the solutions I explained in the question. Which I don't like too much because I need to define handler-functions inside of the `main`/`init` functions. But that's not a big problem, but wanted to know if there are better solutions.